# Consistent font for Plotly PDF containing MathJax

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, mathjax

I am having issues having a consistent font style in Plotly when exporting the plot containing LaTeX to PDF.

See the following link for the same issue that was apparently never resolved:

[Plotly LaTeX fonts different in Jupyter and exported PDF or PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68163066/plotly-latex-fonts-different-in-jupyter-and-exported-pdf-or-png)

Essentially, it happens whenever `r"$latex variable$` is used instead of `"normal text"`. If you run the following code, you'll notice that the LaTeX variables appear bold compared to normal text. I would appreciate help figuring out the solution. Thank you.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create the plot
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 4, 1, 3, 5],
    mode='lines',
    name='Line'
))

fig.update_layout(
    title='This only happens on the PDF!',
    xaxis_title=r'$\Delta \text{ should not be bold, but it is}$',
    yaxis_title='Normal text is not bold',
)

fig.show()

# Save the plot as a PDF file
fig.write_image('plot_with_bold_LaTeX.pdf')
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAOhW.png)

I have already tired different rendering engines such as Orca and Kaleido. I have also tried exporting to SVG and then converting to PDF, but all of the LaTeX cannot be interpreted by ImageMagick nor Inkscape. I suspect the error lies with MathJax similar to how it is described in [Plotly LaTeX fonts different in Jupyter and exported PDF or PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68163066/plotly-latex-fonts-different-in-jupyter-and-exported-pdf-or-png)

OpenAI also suggested adding the following to the Plotly Layout, but it didn't work:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

# Create and configure your Plotly figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add your plotly traces and layout settings here
# ...

# Configure MathJax options in the HTML template
pio.templates.default = dict(
    layout=go.Layout(
        template="plotly",
        meta=dict(
            mathjax="cdn",
            mathjax_config="TeX-AMS-MML_SVG",
        ),
    )
)

# Save the figure as a PDF file
pio.write_image(fig, 'figure.pdf', format='pdf', engine='kaleido')
```

Comment: Hey @Ignacio, yes. There is a temporary solution, but it takes a long time to fix. It involves creating a clone of a fork and building it with Docker. Here is the solution posted by Konmenel:
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3828

Answer (score -1):

The xaxis title isn't bold. Only by  replacing `xaxis_title=r'$\Delta \text{ should not be bold but it is}$`,
with `xaxis_title=r'$\bf\Delta \text{ should not be bold, but it is}$', you'll get a
bold text.
To have a consistent font in pdf define the plot layout as follows:

```
fig.update_layout(width=500, height=400,font_family="Balto", font_size=11,
    title='This only happens on the PDF!',
    xaxis_title=r'$\Delta \text{ should not be bold, but it is}$',
    yaxis_title='Normal text is not bold',
)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Changing the font family does not fix the issue. Try the following after your code and you'll see that the PDF shows text as bold (by which I mean thicker text)

fig.write_image("output_plot.pdf")

It renders just fine with HTML, but not in the PDF which uses MathJax.